# Why eGet in EMF returns Object rather than EObject?

Tags: eclipse, code-generation, modeling, api-design, eclipse-emf

I am working on some code using the EMF framework in Java, but it is really hard to use, e.g. I cannot implement OCL-like query API on top of EMF which would be type-safe.

One of the reasons is that `eGet()` for a `EStructuralFeature` returns just an `Object`, not `EObject`. So anything I would write must use much of null checking, type checking and type casting which is unsafe, not performant and cannot be generalized in a reusable way.

Why doesn't EMF generate dummy implementations with `EObject` wrappers for arbitrary `Object` value?

Implementing the `EObject` and hence the `EClass` interfaces even with simple throw `UnsupportedOperationException` is really a pain (the APIs are too big). The same holds for the `eContainer()` method which makes navigating the model upwards painful.

Comment: I just realized EMF has wrappers for Java's primitive types and their Object equivalents, but the question still remains, why have API which returns Objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The same method is used for accessing simple attribute values (which can be of any Java type) and traverse relationships to other modeled objects, and those can be single or multivalued.

EMF provides generic mechanisms for checking whether an object is an instance of an EClass, or if an EClass is assignable to another, so I don't really see the problem with that.

Comment: BTW, there is no better place to ask this question than the EMF newsgroup: http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=thread&frm_id=108

Comment: Still my first impression is it is no different to Java with primitive types and without autoboxing. I will do some thinking and programming to have create some sensible opinion.

Answer (score 1):

The eGet() method is part of the EMF reflective API. As EMF can wrap any serializable object you cannot restrict the returned object of such a reflective API.

Why do you need to use this reflective API instead of the generated Java implementation of your ecore model? This way you will have all the direct well typed API to manipulate your domain objects.

Comment: I am using Eclipse Xtext and I cannot define arbitrary model elements in the grammar (e.g. typed parent association). When I am writing some services in Xtext (Java code) I need to traverse the model, but without real associations, I have to use the reflective API and cast quite a lot. eGet returning Object won't let me write nice generic code to handle this for me.